# ffmpeg av_read_frame() need very long time to stop

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to decode RTSP video.It likes that:
When it's on the end of file,it block in the av_read_frame() for a long time,why?

Comment: while(av_read_frame()>=0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Various reasons can cause long blocking. But you can control the processing time for a I/O layer.

Use the structure `AVFormatContext::interrupt_callback` to set the interrupt handler.

```
class timeout_handler {
  public:
    timeout_handler(unsigned int t) : timeout_ms_(TimeoutMs){}

    void reset(unsigned int 0) {
      timeout_ms_ = TimeoutMs;
      lastTime_ = my_get_local_time();
    }

    bool is_timeout(){
      const my_time_duration actualDelay = my_get_local_time() - lastTime_;
      return actualDelay > timeout_ms_;
    }

    static int check_interrupt(void * t) {
       return t && static_cast<timeout_handler *>(t)->is_timeout();
    }

 public:
   unsigned int timeout_ms_;
   my_time_t lastTime_;      
 };


 /// .................
 AVFormatContext * ic;
 timeout_handler * th = new timeout_handler(kDefaultTimeout);
 /// .................
 ic->interrupt_callback.opaque = (void*)th ;
 ic->interrupt_callback.callback = &timeout_handler::check_interrupt;
 /// open input
 // avformat_open_input(ic, ... );
 // etc

 /// .................
 /// before any I/O operations, for example:
 th->reset(kDefaultTimeout);
 int e = AVERROR(EAGAIN);
 while (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == e) 
  e = av_read_frame(ic, &packet);
 // If the time exceeds the limit, then the process interruped at the next IO operation.
```

Comment: This problem has been settled.The server send "BYE" packet,then the av_read_frame() can past now.But how to send "TeerDown" packet to the server?

Comment: If the server send `BYE` packet, then the `av_read_frame` should return `AVERROR_EOF`

Answer (score 0):

This problem come because av_read_frame() stuck in network infinite loop
I got the same problem then I have used interrupt call back please refer the sample code

First initialize your context and set interrupt call back

```
AVFormatContext *_formatCtx;

//Initialize format context
_formatCtx=avformat_alloc_context();

//Initialize intrrupt callback
AVIOInterruptCB icb={interruptCallBack,(__bridge void *)(self)};
_formatCtx->interrupt_callback=icb;
```

now handle the interrupt in your callback

```
int interruptCallBack(void *ctx){

   //once your preferred time is out you can return 1 and exit from the loop
   if(timeout){
      //exit
      return 1;
    }

   //continue 
   return 0;

}
```