# ffmpeg av_read_frame is blocked long time

Tags: ffmpeg, block, rtsp

```
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0) {
    if (packet->stream_index == videoindex) {
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, packet);
        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("Decode Error.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Succeed to decode 1 frame! %d\n", tt++);
    }
    av_packet_unref(packet);
}
```

I am using ffmpeg to provide live audio/video RTSP streaming in android.

But I have a trouble from blocking av_read_frame function forever. 
Android Log:

```
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 70
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 71
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 72
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 73
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 74
I/libnav: Succeed to decode 1 frame! 75
blocking forever...
```

Thus I 
 have experimented some code stuffs. I have copied Android jni code about ffmpeg to pc(ubuntu). Above my code is worked without any blocking.

```
Succeed to decode 21122 frame!
Succeed to decode 21123 frame!
Succeed to decode 21124 frame!
...
without blocking ...
```

I guess that this problem is about delay. I have removed avcodec_decode_video2 call in android jni. my code is executed without any blocking.

I have found [ffmpeg av_read_frame() need very long time to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558172/ffmpeg-av-read-frame-need-very-long-time-to-stop) threads. But it can't help me.

If you have a similiar problem, please help me.

Comment: Set socket timeout `av_dict_set_int(&opt, "stimeout", (int64_t)10, 0);` before `avformat_open_input()`, this sets timeout to 10 seconds