# using ASIO to implement interrupt_callback for ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, c++14, libav, asio

I am trying to properly implement an `interrupt_callback` using ASIO timer for `avformat_open_input`, `av_read_frame` and possibly for other functions. I can't get it to work when receiving a udp video stream.

I've written a class that waits for periods of time using ASIO timer. Its constructor takes an `io_context` from the thread of `avformat_open_input` execution and an overall timeout period to wait for. By default it waits for 20 ms each time, but can be set to wait longer periods.

```
class InterruptCallback
{
public:

    constexpr static std::chrono::milliseconds basic_period()
    {
        return std::chrono::milliseconds(20);
    }

    explicit InterruptCallback(asio::io_context &asioContext,
                               std::chrono::milliseconds timeout,
                               std::chrono::milliseconds period =
                               basic_period())
            : waitingPeriod_(period),
              attempts_(timeout / waitingPeriod_),
              timer_(asioContext)
    {
        attempts_ = attempts_ ? attempts_ : 1;
    }

    int wait()
    {
        timer_.expires_after(waitingPeriod_);
        timer_.wait();
        return int(!--attempts_);
    }

    static int wait(void *opaqueCallback)
    {
        auto callback = reinterpret_cast<InterruptCallback *>(opaqueCallback);
        return callback->wait();
    }

private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds waitingPeriod_;
    size_t attempts_;

    asio::steady_timer timer_;
};
```

This approach works when no udp stream is being received. Also it returns relatively fast when a udp *is* being received.

However, when I set a `AVFormatContext::interrupt_callback` I get a lot of errors on decoding.
`avformat_find_stream_info` can return fast enough, but `AVCodecContext` will be invalid.
Or it can take a very long time to execute.

```
    asio::io_context mainThreadContext{};

    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    {
        InterruptCallback interruptCallback{mainThreadContext,
                                            std::chrono::milliseconds(2000)
        };

        pFormatContext->interrupt_callback.callback = &InterruptCallback::wait;
        pFormatContext->interrupt_callback.opaque = &interruptCallback;

        const auto resOpen = avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext,
                                                 containerAddress.c_str(),
                                                 nullptr,
                                                 nullptr);
        if (resOpen < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open stream from: " << containerAddress << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    auto avFormatExit = sg::make_scope_exit(
            [&pFormatContext]
            {
                avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
            });

    pFormatContext->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_NOBUFFER | AVFMT_FLAG_FLUSH_PACKETS;

    int error = avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext, nullptr);
```

It can happen on the line where I query the stream info, but is also frequent for decoding loop.
These are some of the possible errors:

```
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7217 DC, 7217 AC, 7217 MV errors in I frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7588 DC, 7588 AC, 7588 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] error while decoding MB 83 5, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7526 DC, 7526 AC, 7526 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7072 DC, 7072 AC, 7072 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7651 DC, 7651 AC, 7651 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 5806 DC, 5806 AC, 5806 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] error while decoding MB 0 5, bytestream 8107
[h264 @ 00000000027f4000] concealing 7609 DC, 7609 AC, 7609 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6669 DC, 6669 AC, 6669 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7254 DC, 7254 AC, 7254 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7048 DC, 7048 AC, 7048 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7061 DC, 7061 AC, 7061 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7220 DC, 7220 AC, 7220 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 5722 DC, 5722 AC, 5722 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7230 DC, 7230 AC, 7230 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7085 DC, 7085 AC, 7085 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7745 DC, 7745 AC, 7745 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6907 DC, 6907 AC, 6907 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7301 DC, 7301 AC, 7301 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 5664 DC, 5664 AC, 5664 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 105 8, bytestream -8
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7144 DC, 7144 AC, 7144 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7487 DC, 7487 AC, 7487 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6912 DC, 6912 AC, 6912 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 39 8, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7210 DC, 7210 AC, 7210 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 5262 DC, 5262 AC, 5262 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 54 8, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7195 DC, 7195 AC, 7195 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7298 DC, 7298 AC, 7298 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6819 DC, 6819 AC, 6819 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 5692 DC, 5692 AC, 5692 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6684 DC, 6684 AC, 6684 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7600 DC, 7600 AC, 7600 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6123 DC, 6123 AC, 6123 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7689 DC, 7689 AC, 7689 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6846 DC, 6846 AC, 6846 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 0 10, bytestream 1892
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7009 DC, 7009 AC, 7009 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 5288 DC, 5288 AC, 5288 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7932 DC, 7932 AC, 7932 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7039 DC, 7039 AC, 7039 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 105 11, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6784 DC, 6784 AC, 6784 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6918 DC, 6918 AC, 6918 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 6483 DC, 6483 AC, 6483 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] error while decoding MB 118 1, bytestream -10
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] concealing 7971 DC, 7971 AC, 7971 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 00000000027dea40] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] QP 4294967266 out of range
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000051a0040] no frame!
Error sending packet for decoding

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I **don't** set an `interrupt_callback`, no errors occur, stream info is found very quickly.

So, the questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong when implementing the interrupt callback?
2. Why don't I get an error when I receive an invalid codec context from `avformat_find_stream_info`?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here but... your callback `InterruptCallback::wait` blocks for 20ms each time it's invoked.  20ms is a *long* time if you're receiving media streams via UDP.  I suspect you're missing a lot of packets.

Comment: @G.M. I see. AFAIC on Windows and Linux it is impossible to wait for less than 20 milliseconds. Does it mean that I should give up on the idea of using ASIO timer and basically anything but busy waiting or spin lock?

Comment: I don't think `boost.asio` is the way to go here.  Instead, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558172/ffmpeg-av-read-frame-need-very-long-time-to-stop) is probably closer to what you want (and could be rewritten to make use of `std::chrono`).

Comment: @G.M. well it seems like busy waiting for me.

Comment: Why do you want to wait?